# javascript array object overwriting previous objects even though I'm creating new references

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, scope

I'm from a c# c++ background and I'm confused about something that is happening.

**Inside the scope** of my function I am creating a new object before pushing it onto an 'array'. When I create the new object, it seems to be referencing the same object that was previously added to the array, even though I'm not assigning to the same variable. This is confusing because in c# this code would be creating a new object then adding the new object to the array. How do I get around this in javascript? Even using 'let', which I thought should stay in the scope I defined, does not seem to work

function:

```
  addPurchaseOrderItem() {
    this.purchaseOrderItems.push(new PurchaseOrder("","","","",1,100,""));
    console.log(this.purchaseOrderItems);
    // this.showNewPurchaseOrderItem = true;
  }
```

another version that still does not work:

```
 addPurchaseOrderItem() {
    let temp = new PurchaseOrder("","","","",1,100,"");
    this.purchaseOrderItems.push(temp);
    console.log(this.purchaseOrderItems);
    // this.showNewPurchaseOrderItem = true;
  }
```

purchase order class:

```
export class PurchaseOrder {
    public poNumber: string;
    public siteLocation: string;
    public lineItem: string;
    public manufacture: string;
    public partNum: string;
    public qTY: number;
    public acquisitionCost: number;
    public itemDescription: string

    constructor(
        siteLocation: string,
        lineItem: string,
        manufacture: string,
        partNum: string,
        qTY: number,
        acquisitionCost: number,
        itemDescription: string
        )
    {
        this.siteLocation = siteLocation;
        this.lineItem = lineItem;
        this.manufacture = manufacture;
        this.partNum = partNum;
        this.qTY = qTY;
        this.acquisitionCost = acquisitionCost;
        this.itemDescription = itemDescription
    }
}
```

here is the live example (stackblitz):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rvkjoa

Comment: Nothing shown indicates anything to do with symptoms mentioned

Comment: please create a minimal reproducible example of your problem

Comment: @charlietfl here is the live plunker. I'm new to this but I think it shows my problem. Click the add button to add new objects to the array

Comment: @Goku There's something wrong with your plunker link, there's nothing there but a blank starter template.

Comment: @nullptr.t used stackblitz since plunkr is having some problems.

Comment: @charlietfl would you look at my updated stackblitz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is populated correctly. It looks like you have the same `id's` and Angular always shows the first row everywhere. Your array items are not the same. It can be seen from the following code:

```
<!-- The above code omitted for the brevity -->
<button (click)="addPurchaseOrderItem()"> Add</button>
<p>purchaseOrderItems {{ purchaseOrderItems | json }} </p>
```

You should just delete the `id` attributes because they are always the same in your loop:

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="saveAllChangesToDatabase(form)">
    <table style="width:100%; margin: 0 auto;">
    <tr style="text-align: left;">
      <th>QTY</th>
      <th>Acq. Cost$</th>
      <th>Item Description</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let purchaseOrder of purchaseOrderItems">
      <td>
        <input name="qTY" [(ngModel)]="purchaseOrder.qTY" type="text" size="3%"  required>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="acquisitionCost" [(ngModel)]="purchaseOrder.acquisitionCost" type="text" size="5%"  required>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="itemDescription" [(ngModel)]="purchaseOrder.itemDescription" type="text" size="35%" required>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button style="margin-top: 2em"style="height: 2em; width: 100%; margin-top: .5em" (click)="addPurchaseOrderItem()"> Add</button>

  <p>purchaseOrderItems {{ purchaseOrderItems | json }} </p>

</form>
```

UPDATE:

Just delete `form` tag to avoid of disappearing data

```
<table style="width:100%; margin: 0 auto;">
    <tr style="text-align: left;">
      <th>QTY</th>
      <th>Acq. Cost$</th>
      <th>Item Description</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let purchaseOrder of purchaseOrderItems">
      <td>
        <input name="qTY" [(ngModel)]="purchaseOrder.qTY" type="text" size="3%"  required>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="acquisitionCost" [(ngModel)]="purchaseOrder.acquisitionCost" type="text" size="5%"  required>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="itemDescription" [(ngModel)]="purchaseOrder.itemDescription" type="text" size="35%" required>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button style="margin-top: 2em"style="height: 2em; width: 100%; margin-top: .5em" (click)="addPurchaseOrderItem()"> Add</button>

  <p>purchaseOrderItems {{ purchaseOrderItems | json }} </p>
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and updated the StackBlitz, but the UI is still not reflecting it. Got any suggestions?

Comment: @Goky it works. I've opened your link and edited your data. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rvkjoa . Try to edit your data.

Comment: I mean how do I get the changes to stay. after I press add the item description disappears from the table even though the array is updated.

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work without removing the form? I need the form for validation

Comment: @Goku Yeah, you can do validation like this: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51599143/angular-5-dynamic-form-validation-inside-a-table
or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44158712/reactive-form-for-each-table-row and plunker example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vcjjfr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has 3 data types that are passed by reference: Array, Function and Object. Anything else is pass by value. Solution can be found in following post.
[JavaScript: How to pass object by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574054/javascript-how-to-pass-object-by-value)

Comment: but am I not creating a new reference in my example code?

Comment: Looks like there is nothing wrong with pushing new object into the array. It's working like you expected. i.e. 'creating a new object then adding the new object to the array.' The issue is with your UI code not reflecting new values that's already in the array. If you change the values already in the form and click the add button, then check console log and open the array, you will find that values already in array changed.